# Unable to merge dex error after adding library

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I've been trying to add the design library but everytime i do it i get this unable to merge dex error

i've tried using different versions of SDK's already and other design versions but it dosen't seem to be working

Here is an image of the error:
[image]

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.javiersantos:BottomDialogs:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.mancj:SlideUp-Android:1.0-beta'
    compile 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'

 }
```

Sorry for such messy dependencies but i've been trying everything to get this fixed but nothing because i need the design library

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I found the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) that work for me.

Add some config to **app/build.gradle:**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Comment: So maybe you can add some more config to **build.gradle**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

```

Comment: @Novel please do not post pictures, but actual code/error text.